# How to escape "," comma when convert xml to csv

Tags: marklogic

[image]I have a sample code to convert xml to csv, but when I open a csv file in excel.  I see three columns because of Abstract element has comma ",". How can I fix it to escape comma ",".  Thanks

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace mdr="http://learning-convert-xml-csv.com/record";
declare namespace meta="http://learning-convert-xml-csv.com/meta";

let $doc := <records xmlns:record="http://learning-convert-xml-csv.com/record">
           <meta:Metadata xmlns:meta="http://learning-convert-xml- csv.com/meta">
           <meta:Title>Beginning MarkLogic with XQuery.</meta:Title>
           <meta:Abstract>In software engineering and computer science, abstraction is a technique for arranging complexity of computer systems          </meta:Abstract>
```

```
let $Title := ($doc/meta:Metadata/meta:Title)
let $Title := fn:string-join($Title,",")

let $abstract:=      ($doc/meta:Metadata/meta:Abstract)
let $abstract:=      fn:string-join($abstract,",")

let $quote:=
for $myData in ($Title,$abstract)
  return fn:concat("'",$myData,"'")

let $output :=
         text{
               fn:concat(fn:string-join(($quote),","),"&#x0D;&#x0A;"
               )
         }

 return xdmp:save(fn:concat("c:\temp\","test.csv"),$output)
```

Comment: If you are putting quotes around your rows in CSV, then for excel, this should not be a problem.  Please post an example of your csv file so that people can have more context around the problem.

Comment: However the code fn:concat("""",$value,"""") will not work if a $value has a double quote " " in sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes to quote values in your CSV. Using that you don't need to escape any other character except double quote itself, which you do by doubling it. Good CSV parsers should even be able to parse line-ends within values, as long as double quotes are used.

See also RFC 4180: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

HTH!